# Column with end of file name python

Tags: python, pandas, filenames

I have a code that merges all txt files from a directory into a dataframe

follow the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

diretorio = "F:\PROJETOS\LOTE45\ARQUIVOS\RISK\RISK_CUSTOM_FUND_N1" 
files = [] 

files = [pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\t')
     for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(diretorio ,"*.txt"))]


df = pd.concat(files, ignore_index=True)
df
```

that gives result to this table

[image]

I needed to add a date column to this table, but I only have the date available at the end of the filename.

[image]

How can I get the date at the end of the filename and put it inside the dataframe.

I have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

diretorio = "F:/PROJETOS/LOTE45/ARQUIVOS/RISK/RISK_CUSTOM_FUND_N1/"
files = []
for filename in os.listdir(diretorio):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        df = pd.read_csv(diretorio + filename, sep=";")
        df['Date'] = filename.split('.')[0].split("_")[-1]
        files.append(df)
df = pd.concat(files, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file naming pattern is constant, you can parse the end of the filename for every iteration of the loop this way :-

```
from datetime import datetime

files = []

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(diretorio ,"*.txt")):
  df_f = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\t')
  df_f['date'] = datetime.strptime(file[-11:-4], "%d%m%Y")
  files.append(df_f)

df = pd.concat(files, ignore_index=True)
```